# Globs in sonar-project.properties

Tags: java, sonarqube, glob

I'm working on a large legacy project that I'm trying to componentize, starting with SonarQube. I'm configuring a multi-module project in `sonar-project.properties`. This works fine. However, I have an issue precisely identifying source folders.

Unfortunately, our modules aren't neatly separated in the file system. The project is separated into many Eclipse projects, and several Eclipse projects together form one module. I can, of course, enumerate all the projects, but this is very cumbersome as there are a lot of them. Here's a (simplified) version of our directory structure:

```
projects/
    moduleAsubmodule1/
        src/
            com/mycompany/moduleA/submodule1/
    moduleAsubmodule2/
        src/
            com/mycompany/moduleA/submodule2/
    moduleBsubmodule1/
        src/
            com/mycompany/moduleB/submodule1/
    moduleBsubmodule2/
        src/
            com/mycompany/moduleB/submodule2/
    moduleBsubmodule3/
        src/
            com/mycompany/moduleB/submodule3/
```

Imagine many more modules and submodules, where the project name is concatenated, but the package names are nicely divided, making it much easier to differentiate on those.

```
moduleA.sonar.projectBaseDir=.
moduleA.sonar.sources=projects/**/src/com/mycompany/moduleA/**/*
moduleA.sonar.test=projects/**/*.test/src/com/mycompany/moduleA/**/*
```

According to [the documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/), this should be possible for exclusions. However, I get the following error message:

```
16:10:44 ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
16:10:44 ERROR: Caused by: The folder 'projects/**/src/com/mycompany/mymodule/**/*' does not exist for 'XXX:XXX:mymodule' (base directory = D:\XxxSonar\.)
```

So I guess globs don't work for sources? If that's indeed the case, what can I do?

We use SonarQube 4.1.2.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, but I solved it by doing like this:

```
sonar.sources=.
sonar.inclusions=projects/*/src/**/*
```

The inclusions/exclusions properties support wildcards. Same for your tests:

```
sonar.test.inclusions=projects/*/*.test/src/**/*
```

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards are not allowed when specifying "sonar.sources". Instead, you should play with the properties that allow to narrow your source and test files. See [the documentation page on how to include or exclude files to narrow the focus](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/).

Comment: Unfortunately, the 'narrow the focus' help page (which I already linked to in the question) did not help me in figuring this out. It's not clear to me which property I can play with to achieve what I want here. I've updated the question so that it more clearly shows what our directory structure looks like; hope that helps.